# How can I make tables respect the grid in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, grid-layout

Bootstrap tables do not respect the grid even if they have col-xs-X classes defined.

Here's a minimal example that shows how the (red) table doesn't line up with the (gray) grid: http://jsfiddle.net/fm65v3e0/

```css
.col-xs-1 {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

th {
  background-color: #fee;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
             <th class="col-xs-5">
               5-col header
             </th>
             <th class="col-xs-3">
               3-col header
             </th>
             <th class="col-xs-4">
               4-col header
             </th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Because the table appears within a column it has a certain amount of padding around the outside. If I remove the padding from columns the table lines up but of course now any text inside a column will be flush against the next column.

Additionally, Bootstrap tables are 100% width by default and apportion any "spare" space if you don't use all 12 columns.

My site is almost entirely tabular data so if I don't have my tables respect the grid it's a bit like I'm not using a grid at all. Do you think I can solve this easily? Is it a mistake to try and solve it/care about this?

Comment: Can you provide a MCV example of your code? (1) can't be solved within bootstrap, you'd need to tackle that with adding your very own CSS rules which can't function the way Bootstrap Grid works (as that works with floats) . (2) I'm not sure I understand this one, that's why I would like to see that MCV https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Annnd completely rewrote the question because now I have this simple example there's no need to get into my site specific stuff :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bootstrap CSS adds `padding-right: 15px` and `padding-left: 15px` to all of the `col-xx-xx` elements.

Remove or override the padding and things should become aligned properly.  The below image shows what happens in your Bootply when the padding is removed.
[image]

One way to override this is to create a class called `no-padding` like so:

```
.no-padding {
     padding-left: 0;
     padding-right: 0;
}
```

and apply it to any elements where you do not want padding applied.  Here's an updated demo showing this:

```css
.col-xs-1 {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

th {
  background-color: #fee;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.no-padding {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding"> <!-- Add it Here -->
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
             <th class="col-xs-5">
               5-col header
             </th>
             <th class="col-xs-3">
               3-col header
             </th>
             <th class="col-xs-4">
               4-col header
             </th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works for the tables, but now anything that *isn't* in a table is flush up against the edge of the column. (See the "col"s and how they touch the edge of their box).

I suppose that when two columns containing tables are next to each other I will have to put an empty column between them. So I could do that for all columns. Set the gutter of the grid to 0 and use empty columns to separate content horizontally. (I'm actually customizing Bootstrap to use 24 columns so this is less space-wasteful than it sounds.) I'll give it a spin!

Comment: You can create a new class with no padding and apply it only to your tables, updated my answer to include jsfiddle showing this

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Now I have a new but highly related question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060539/nested-rows-in-bootstrap-3-fail-to-respect-the-grid

Comment: The answer to that one is pretty much the same as this one, it's the same padding that gets applied to the nested row.

Comment: I don't think so. I seem to have the same problem if I remove all padding from the columns. The problem is that my page is 12 columns wide. Let's call the width of one of those columns x. If I make a column that is 10x wide and subdivide it into 5/12ths and 7/12ths of itself in a nested row I get weird sizes that don't correspond to any whole number of x. 4.167x and 5.833x. Unless I'm misunderstanding how to nest rows in Boostrap completely (very possible!)

Comment: 5/12 = .4167 - if you take a 10x wide column and divide it by 5/12 that's what the result should be

Comment: Right, but a 4.167 cols-wide div in my page won't align correctly with everything else on the page. Which is (?) the whole point of grid systems. I either need to nest in a less complicated way or go up to a huge number of columns so I can always math correctly and get alignment with the "higher up" grid columns.

Comment: So do 4/10 column, or 11/20