# Nested rows in Bootstrap 3 fail to respect the grid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

Bootstrap seems to break its own grid once you get into nested rows. This is a good example:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5">nested col-xs-5</div>
        <div class="col-xs-7">nested col-xs-7</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would expect to be able to make the "nested xs-col-*" columns line up exactly with the 12 cols at the top. It also doesn't work if I make the inner classes col-xs-3/col-xs-7 (adding up to 10 like the containing col). That just leaves a gap at the right.

Is it correct to say that Bootstrap won't actually let you respect the grid once you get into nested rows if you use odd widths? Or am I doing it wrong?

It seems to me that whole point of a grid is that things should be aligned. Do I have to stay away from (nontrivial) nested rows if I want perfect alignment?

Comment: I think it has to do with that Bootstrap is percentage based. So in your top level columns, col-X-1 is 8.3333 percent of all the available width. Then the inner level is 8.333 percent of a row that is 83.34 percent of the total width. So your col-X-1 is not anymore 8.3333 percent of total width, but 8.333 percent of 83.34%

Comment: I think you're right. But that means that (unless you use the customize option, go to a huge number of columns and math it up) complex nesting will not be able to align to your grid. Which is the whole point of a grid, isn't it? Maybe I'm being overly prescriptive or trying to achieve overly complicated nesting. (I *actually* want to get table columns to respect the grid.)

Comment: Gleb has a good answer. You are limited to proportions that ends in a integer digit, not fractions. That way you will be able to do perfectly aligned grids. http://nateroling.com/2014/12/15/aligning-nested-grids/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1) Pick the proportions

Nested row also uses a 12-columns grid. So you asked Bootstrap to take `5/12` from `10 parent columns`. But this is a fractional number. Because of this column boundaries do not coincide with each other.

Pick the proportions between the columns. For example:

- `4/12` from `9 parent columns` is exactly `3 parent columns`
- `3/12` from `8 parent columns` is exactly `2 parent columns`

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">nested 4</div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">nested 8</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">nested 3</div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">nested 9</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### 2) Simplify the layout

You can do the same without nested columns:

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div><div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">3 columns</div>
    <div class="col-xs-7">7 columns</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">4 columns</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">6 columns</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">col</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Glad I wasn't missing wrong about Bootstrap usage :) My real life problem is somewhat more complicated but I will have to simplify. My current non-responsive grid has table columns that are 1-col wide inside a 22-col main area which is inside the overall 24-col grid. Sometimes these tables are nested in other columns! To support this with integer math I'd have to go up to 168 columns for the main grid and having 2x12-col margins around a 144 column content area. Overkill! I'll try and instead have my margins off the edge of my grid and make a simpler 24 cols. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to not use Bootstrap for your grid system.

http://shelvesgrid.org/ has as one of it's top 3 selling points that, "Shelves is the only fluid grid where the nested columns line up the grid, no matter how deep you go."

The trick used there is to use percentage widths all the way down but have nested percentage widths know they are nested.

For example in this situation (assuming a 12 column grid):

```
<div class="column-6">
    <div class="column-2"></div>
    <div class="column-2"></div>
    <div class="column-2"></div>
</div>
```

Shelves applies CSS that looks like this:

```
.column-2 { width: 16.6666667%; }
.column-6 { width: 50%; }
.column-6 .column-2 { 33.333333% }
```

The more specific later rule overrides the base definition of the width of a column-2 so that it will be the same size when nested in a .column-6 as it would be at the top level.

It's a pretty neat trick to have a grid that works "all the way down" so that column-2 always means 2/12ths of your grid and doesn't change its meaning (and break the grid) once you are nested.

(Sadly Shelves uses margin for the spacing between columns, not padding, and that caused problems for me so I ended up rolling my own using the above trick.)